# Is environ available on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, environment-variables

Is `environ` variable (as of POSIX) available (at least for reading) in major Windows C compilers?

I know that `execve` is available on Windows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)

But I am unsure if `environ` is available, too.

Comment: Windows once tried to add POSIX compatibility, but it was long ago and only half-hearted. If you want POSIX in Windows use explicit environment or libraries for that, like e.g. Cygwin.

Comment: Is the function [`getenv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=vs-2017) what you need?

Comment: @WeatherVane No, `getenv` is not exactly what I want, because I want to pass the value of `environ` to `execve()`. Using `getenv` is less efficient than usage of the variable `environ` would be

Comment: The global `environ` var has been deprecated for several decades in UNIX based systems. Don't use it. If you don't want to pass a custom environment to a new process just use `execv()` rather than `execve()`.

Comment: @KurtisRader `environ` is not marked as deprecated in the Linux manpage `environ`. Where can I read about its deprecation? I wanted just to pass (indirectly through another function) `environ` to `execve()` to indicate that I inherit the parent environment

Comment: @KurtisRader Isn't reading `environ` the only way to read the environment vars in Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

environ should be available, but is deprecated and you should use the more secure methods.

The `execXX()` calls are available, but `fork()` isn't, so effectively the exec functions are rendered useless.

You can use `CreateProcessA` for similar effect, and have the ability to set up environments and pipes cleanly.

Just to acknowledge @eryksun 's concerns: You do need to consider which character set you are using before using any Microsoft "A" file (and other O/S) APIs. It is simplest if you can do all your code using 16bit unicode, as that is the underlying type for NT, Windows 7, Windows 10. On unix and mac, you can make assumptions that utf-8 is the 8-bit character set of choice, but that has yet to happen for windows, and of course "backward compatibility". If you are using **any** of the "unix-like" M/S API, you should already be making the same design decisions, though, so should already have an answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your answer. Now I know that my software does not work on Windows, because it uses `fork()`

Comment: ANSI codepages are a legacy feature that should be avoided. Use `CreateProcessW` instead, with native UTF-16LE strings. Decode arguments from UTF-8 if your code otherwise uses `char *` strings.

Comment: The problem with `exec*` in the C runtime isn't just the absence of `fork`. There is no `exec` system-call support to replace the image of a running process. So the CRT simply emulates it with a `spawn` call, which is not even close to the semantics of `exec` that are expected by Unix devs.

Comment: @eryksun True enough, but if you are trying to translate unix code, the presence of the A methods is very convenient :-)

Comment: @GemTaylor, it's convenient until a file or environment variable name (e.g. `"%username%"`) gets mangled with "?" characters and best-fit mappings such as "α" -> "a". In practice it's a mess. Use Unicode. For Windows, shim in a UTF-8 <=> UTF-16LE layer to adapt existing code.

Comment: Does windows mot support a utf8 mbcs mode, then? Disappointing!

Comment: Windows 10 has beta support for UTF-8 in the ANSI API. It's not on by default last I checked. But most of us still have to support at least Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I was wrong; looks like the MSVC runtime library does include support for [`environ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/environ-wenviron?view=vs-2017) (though deprecated) after all. I will leave my previous answer below if anyone is interested in alternative methods.

---

<s>Not that I'm aware of, but, if you want to access the environment-variables on Windows, you have some options:</s>

1. Declare `main` or `wmain` with the following signature:

   ```
   int (w)main(int argc, char/wchar_t *argv[], char/wchar_t *envp[])
   ```

   This is defined in the C Standard as a pointer to the environment block, if applicable:

   > **§ J.5.1**:
   >
   > In a hosted environment, the main function receives a third argument, char *envp[],
   >   that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to char, each of which points to a string
   >   that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program
   >   (5.1.2.2.1).
2. Use the Windows API function [`GetEnvironmentVariable(A|W)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable) to get an individual environment variable, or [`GetEnvironmentStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187(v=VS.85).aspx) to get the entire environment array.
3. The standard C function [`getenv`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getenv.htm).

Comment: Yes, but your link about `environ` says: *This global variable has been deprecated for the more secure functional versions `getenv_s`, `_wgetenv_s` and `_putenv_s`, `_wputenv_s`, which should be used in place of the global variable.*

Comment: @WeatherVane Right, so, MS doesn't recommend it, but it's still there, which is what OP was asking.

Comment: It might be because of Microsoft's general "more secure" policy with their suffixed `_s` versions of standard functions. Note their comment does not exclude the standard `getenv`.

Answer (score 2):

The following program will print the environment variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[]){
    int e = 0;
    while (env[e] != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", env[e++]);
    }
}
```